# mysql filter user and friends' posts by month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to filter user and friends' post by month.

This is the structure of my tables:

```
Friends
id    username    friend
1     kyle        jan
2     jan         kyle
3     kyle        nic
4     nic         kyle


Posts
id    title           username    date
1     hello world     kyle        2015-01-02
2     hola mundo      jan         2015-02-02
3     como estas      nic         2015-02-03
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT(p.title), p.date, p.username
                    FROM posts AS p
                    LEFT JOIN friends AS f
                      ON 
                      p.username = f.username
                      OR p.username = f.friend
                    WHERE p.username = 'kyle'
                    AND MONTH(p.date) = 1
                      OR f.username = 'kyle'
                      OR f.friend = 'kyle'
```

But the result still gets all those posts and not filtered. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Please check my sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9980d/2

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works on the whole select row!!! (SELECT DISTINCT(b.title), b.date eq. SELECT DISTINCT b.title, b.date eq SELECT DISTINCT b.title, (b.date) etc...

Comment: You where statement looks wrong Can you explain what it should do?

Comment: I'm assuming you'd want a parenthesis around what comes after AND.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson yes

Comment: @Jens it should display user and friends' posts

Comment: Remove the "OR f.username = 'kyle' OR f.friend = 'kyle'" part from the WHERE clause? (Kyle already decided by JOIN condition.)

Comment: @jarlh if I remove that i will get no result. Please check my sql fiddle. I updated my post. thanks.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes if i remove the or statements in where clause i get exactly 1 row.

Comment: Start it all over, do the SELECT and JOIN, then add month condition etc, one at the time, and see what works well, and what goes wrong.

Comment: @Jens did you try in the sql fiddle? I got no results :(

Comment: Yes i have done there.

Comment: Can you give me your sql so I could test it. ty

Comment: This is the select i have tired `SELECT DISTINCT(p.title), p.date, p.username
                    FROM posts AS p
                    LEFT JOIN friends AS f
                      ON 
                      p.username = f.username
                      OR p.username = f.friend
                    WHERE p.username = 'kyle'
                    AND MONTH(p.date) = 1`

Comment: @Jens but if month is Feb it's not displaying posts of kyle's friends (AND MONTH(p.date) = 1)

Comment: Because you have `p.username = 'kyle' ` in your where statement. in this case the username `posts`is `jan` look like you have to use `f.username = 'kyle' `

Comment: @Jens still the same dude

Comment: Try this `SELECT DISTINCT(p.title), p.date, p.username
                    FROM posts AS p
                    LEFT JOIN friends AS f
                      ON 
                      p.username = f.username
                      OR p.username = f.friend
                    WHERE MONTH(p.date) = 2
                      AND( f.username = 'kyle'
                      OR f.friend = 'kyle')`